# Return type dependent on input type in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, polymorphism

The following function in Python can returns a list no matter if the input is a `list`, a `numpy.array` or a `pandas.Series`.

What is the pythonic way to write it so that the output type is the same as the input type?

```
def foo(input):
    output = []

    output.append(input[0])

    for i in range(1, len(input)-1):
        if (some condition):
            output.append(input[i])

    output.append(input[-1])

    return output
```

Comment: It should be already? Can you give an example where this is not working?

Comment: The quickest fix would be `return type(input)(output)`, assuming that the type can, in fact, construct an instance given a list of values. If not, you'll have to have some idea of what types `input` can have, and write your function to the lowest common denominator, using only functions known to work with any of them.

Comment: @Raphael The function returns a `list` no matter what type the input is.

Comment: @chepner oh I assumed input is a list, too. I thought they meant that the elements of the input and output list should be the same type.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't do this without making a lot of assumptions about what the input *is*.

The first step would be to make sure that `output` is the right type, not a list.

```
output = type(self)()
```

However, this assumes that whatever type your input is, you can create an instance by calling it with no arguments.

Next, you have to restrict yourself to operations on `output` that are supported by all expected inputs. Not all iterables support an `append` method (`set`, for instance, uses `add`, not `append`), and not all iterables support `__getitem__` (a generator, for instance). This means that you can't generalize your function *too* much; you always have to keep in mind which types of input you will support.

Alternatively, if the set of types you want to support can create an instance from a list, you can let `output = []` stand, but convert it just before returning:

```
return type(self)(output)
```